# Sending UDP packet to destination on different subnet on LAN

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, routes, udp

I have a udp socket server written in C/C++ and a udp client written in C#. I can send packets back and forth, where the server simply echo's back the clients broadcasted message. However, when I send a udp packet to tell the server to reconfigure its network settings (IP, subnet, gateway, DNS) and rebind the adapter to refresh the settings, the client cannot receive the servers echo back anymore.

From what I have read so far, now that the server has different settings it could very well be on a different subnet on the same LAN. My question is how to send the packet back to the broadcasting client? I use the sendto() WIN32 api function, which sends the message to the IP Address and port it got from the broadcasted message. Is there another function that could send the packet back to the specific MAC of the client, therefore skipping the different subnet part? Or is there a different way to send the UDP packet across a local subnet?

Comment: from what I understand,you need a gateway on your server's new subnet which can route the UDP reply from server to your client's subnet.I hope you already have that. may be you can try addng some delay before the server sends reply to allow for network settings to take place.

Comment: @hiteshradia - that sounds like a good solution. One question, if somebody puts in a random gateway (valid, but random), will it still know to route back to the ipaddress and port supplied by the sendto() function? Or do I need to do something to watch that?

Comment: Random gateway might or might not know anything about source and target networks. You are making a mistake of trying to configure IP using IP. Look at how DHCP operates, building a glue between L2 and L3.